# jQuery Mobile - how to force that page recreation - pagebeforecreate event

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I have a small jQuery mobile site.

- it's all single `.html` file
- it's has some edit functionality (view, edit, save)
- all works with `ajax/json/web service`

Most of my pages are using data from `web service, via AJAX & JSON`, so I am using the following a lot:

```
$(document).on( 'pagebeforecreate', '#monday', function() {

// do some stuff on before create, load data with AJAX

});
```

Now, how do I **FORCE that page recreation (pagebeforecreate event)** so the AJAX inside is run again (get the latest data from server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pageBeforeShow` instead of `pageBeforeCreate`.

From the jqm [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html), about creation events.

> Note that these events will only fire once per "page", as opposed to the show/hide events, which fire every time a page is shown and hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a function that you can call when the `pagebeforecreate` event fires and whenever else you want to update the site:

```
function myUpdateFunc() {
    // load data w/ AJAX
}

$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#monday', function () {
    //do some stuff on `pagebeforecreate`

    myUpdateFunc();
});
```

Now you can call the `myUpdateFunc()` function from anywhere in the scope that it's declared.

Also, you can use `.trigger()` to trigger an event, to run the code in an event handler for the event:

```
$('#monday').trigger('pagebeforecreate');
```

Answer (score 1):

Force page recreation/refresh with this code:

```
function refreshPage() {
  $.mobile.changePage(
    window.location.href,
    {
      allowSamePageTransition : true,
      transition              : 'none',
      showLoadMsg             : false,
      reloadPage              : true
    }
  );
}
```

Taken and tested from [here](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/29/reload-the-same-page-without-blinking-on-jquery-mobile/).

Comment: This is making my website going back to a login screen.

Comment: Change window.location.href with id of your page, example: '#page'

Comment: This is also a very good tip how to change the default back button destination.

Comment: Yes but in case of back button use this line:         $.mobile.changePage( "#page", {transition: "none"); also use any transition you want